# Not able to pass value to html email template with nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express

i am trying to print the value in html like {{username}} but its not happening looked on some example but they were not using seperate file for html template

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
const route = express.Router();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile('/index.html');
});



var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     service: 'gmail',
     auth: {
          user: 'paramjeetrtr@gmail.com',
          pass: '',
     },
});

var mailOptions = {
     from: 'paramjeetrtr@gmail.com',
     to: 'shubhtomar30may@gmail.com',
     subject: 'Risposta Application Password',
     context: {
          username: "shubh",
          whatever: "dont know",
     },
     // text: 'That was easy!',
     html: { path: './mail.html', name: 'shubh'},
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
     if (error) {
          console.log(error);
     } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
     }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

now i just need to send value to html file and print it there then it will be done